# Retornar o menor valor usando o Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Sou bastante inexperiente é verdade, mas criei coragem e vim aqui perguntar..
Estou preso há algumas horas em uma solução que aparentemente teria tudo pra ser simples, mas não consigo enxergar uma saída.

Eu tenho dois models, em um deles eu tenho a informação básica do produto (descrição, foto, etc) e no outro eu tenho informações específicas daquela embalagem, como quantidade na embalagem e preço.

Por exemplo:

> Produto : Coca Cola 2 lts
>
> Embalagens
>
> UN:1 - 6,99
>
> CX:12 - 83,88

Eu preciso fazer uma pesquisa que me retorne o menor preço das embalagens cadastradas por produto.

O SQL seria esse:

```
select DESCRICAO,
       (select min(PRECO)
        from PRODUTOEMBALAGEM
        where PRODUTO.ID = PRODUTOEMBALAGEM.IDPRODUTO) as PRECO
from PRODUTO
inner join PRODUTOEMBALAGEM on PRODUTO.ID = PRODUTOEMBALAGEM.IDPRODUTO
where IDESTABELECIMENTO = 1
group by PRODUTO.ID, PRODUTO.DESCRICAO
```

Normalmente eu poderia usar uma expressão do tipo

```
contexto.ProdutoEmbalagens.Min(c => c.Preco)
```

No entanto, eu estou tentando trazer informações do produto também:

```
var produtos =
                    (from prod in contexto.Produtos
                     join emb in contexto.ProdutoEmbalagems on prod.Id equals emb.IdProduto
                     where prod.IdEstabelecimento == idEstabelecimento
                     select new
                     {
                         prod.Id,
                         prod.Descricao,
                         emb.Embalagem,
                         emb.Quantidade,
                         emb.Preco
                     }).ToList();
```

Alguma ideia? Sei que certamente a solução é simples, mas já fritei a cabeça :(

Comment: Faça uma consulta para te retornar as embalagens cadastradas por produto, e com o retorno disso você executa a expressão `contexto.ProdutoEmbalagens.Min(c => c.Preco)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimente da seguinte forma:

```
var produtos =  (from prod in contexto.Produtos
                 join emb in contexto.ProdutoEmbalagems on prod.Id equals emb.IdProduto
                 where prod.IdEstabelecimento == idEstabelecimento
                 select new
                 {
                     prod.Id,
                     prod.Descricao,
                     emb.Embalagem,
                     emb.Quantidade,
                     Preco = (contexto.ProdutoEmbalagens.Where(r => r.IdProduto == prod.Id).Min(c => c.Preco))
                 }).ToList();
```

Basicamente estamos a utilizar um `SUBSELECT` em LINQ.